# Is it safe to use DC power that you got from main lines for basic circuits?

Tags: circuits

Context: I have a project I want to do (just a basic circuit, like breadboard and LEDs and switches), and I don't want it to run on battery because it's going to be a decoration that runs a lot of the time.
So I read online you can use a USB hub to convert from AC to DC, and then use a simple microUSB cable that you cut and took the black and red wires to get the power, and the particular USB hub I have puts out 5v 2A maximum, and my LEDs run on 3v (but that'll be solved with resistors and whatnot).

So my question is, how safe is it to actually use power gotten from the 120v main lines to use in circuitry? Is there any risk at all?

Comment: Look up DC supplies and you wil find many. Any official bought DC supply **should** be safe although I would be careful  not to draw the maxim current from some very cheap ones.

Comment: Taking superfluous energy (like for silly decorations) is a bigger crime in my book. Power ultimately comes from the sun and if you sat in it for a decent enough period you might get a malignant melanoma and die so, how safe is anything?

Comment: *So I read online you can use a USB hub to convert from AC to DC* That's nonsense! A USB hub is used to share **one** USB port into several ports. Mains AC to low voltage DC is done by a **power supply**. Some USB hubs require such a power supply to work. You can safely use that power for your projects. Same as you could use a USB phone charger (which is actually also just a power supply) to do the same. Always use power supplies from a reputable brand, not a cheap one as they might be unsafe.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'm sorry, I simply used the incorrect word. I meant a USB power supply, like the thing you plug your phone charger into. My bad.

Comment: If it has been designed to be safe and is certified to be safe, it will have one of these logo's on it https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&biw=1250&bih=936&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=sIHkWoGGOKb-jwScuKn4Cg&q=safety+logo+electrical+ul++tuv&oq=safety+logo+electrical+ul++tuv&gs_l=psy-ab.3...47868.48574.0.49057.3.3.0.0.0.0.88.249.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.DjjyQaxbsXA

Comment: If the supply is from a reliable source it is safe. I would do it. If the supply was purchased from a flea market, street vendor, or questionable source, then I wouldn't use it for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not believe markings on any chargers sourced through non-standard supply chains!! For example, Ali, eBay or your local dollar store.

Many are criminally unsafe and can kill you. I have seen creepage distances of ~1mm (should be 8mm+) and metal debris rattling around inside of something marked with fake safety agency approvals and fake Apple "Designed in California" and green dot markings. Printing ink is cheap.

You spend $1-$2 for a USB charger you do NOT get the quality (and more important safety) of an Apple or even Belkin charger. You get Shenzhen street sweepings, which is not acceptable for a device that is safety-critical.

---

If the USB charger is approved and of good quality there should be no more danger  than with using any other mains-powered device. Better ones have OVP protection to protect your circuit in case of a failure of the charger. Most should be short-circuit proof and provided you don't apply any outside voltages to the output should be reasonably robust.